# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation with HABTM association with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models enterprise and deal_event with habtm association. This relation works with create and when I do

```
Enterprise.last.deal_events
```

but throws error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "deal_events_enterprises" does not exist LINE 1: ...CT  "enterprises".* FROM "enterprises" INNER JOIN "deal_even...
```

when I do

```
DealEvent.last.enterprises
```

My models

enterprise.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :deal_events
```

deal_event.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :enterprises
```

migration

```
class CreateDealEventsEnterprisesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :deal_events, :enterprises do |t|
      t.index :deal_event_id
      t.index :enterprise_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be naming the join table as `deal_event_enterprises` (notice no plural deal_event). Your migration looks like this

```
class CreateDealEventEnterprises < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :deal_event_enterprises do |t|
      t.integer :deal_event_id
      t.integer :enterprise_id
    end
  end
end
```

Your `has_and_belongs_to_many`associations should work fine if you migrate your join table as `deal_event_enterprises` with columns `deal_event_id` and `enterprise_id`.

However, would recommend defining your many-to-many relations with `has_many :through` by defining a model class `DealEventEnterprise` for your join table.
This would make your code more verbose and you can add additional logic to your join model when required. Setting up `has_many :through` looks like this:

```
class DealEventEnterprise < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deal_event
  belongs_to :enterprise
end

class Enterprise < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deal_event_enterprises
  has_many :deal_events, through: :deal_event_enterprises
end

class DealEvent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deal_event_enterprises
  has_many :enterprises, through: :deal_event_enterprises
end
```